# Fast Insertion in MySQL Table from php

Tags: php, mysql

I have to insert **50,000** to **16.000.000** rows in MySQL Table from php. It is taking at least 15-20 min to store in database.

To complete my project i have to do it more faster insertion. do anyone having any flexible opinion.

i am using this code

```
for($i=$d;$i<=$fd;$i++)
{   $j = $i-$d+1;
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO information(id, redirection, username, pc, date, time, 
method,text, http, code, data, request, software) VALUES ('".$i."','"
.$_SESSION["redirection"][$j]."','".$_SESSION["username"]$j]."','"
.$_SESSION["pc"][$j]."','".$_SESSION["date"][$j]."','".
$_SESSION["time"][$j]."','".$_SESSION["method"][$j]."','"
.$_SESSION["text"][$j]."','".$_SESSION["http"][$j]."','"
.$_SESSION["code"][$j]."','".$_SESSION["data"][$j]."','"
.$_SESSION["request"][$j]."','".$_SESSION["software"][$j]."')";
mysql_query($sql1);
}
```

Comment: FYI - [Lakh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) == 100,000

Comment: did you try to remove indexes while inserting?

Comment: What is the structure of your database table?

Comment: load file for bulk insert its comparatively faster than insert statement

Comment: code is inserted with question and ya phil 1 lakhs means 1,00,000

Comment: @Uriel_SVK  how would he remove th eindexes dynamically through PHP code while executing the insert query?

Comment: m thinking about your array size of $_SESSION for 100 thousand records... what is source of input records?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Cal. Try this:

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO information(id, redirection, username, pc, date, time, 
method,text, http, code, data, request, software) VALUES ";

<?php
for($i=$d;$i<=$fd;$i++)
{   
    $j = $i-$d+1;
    $sql1 .= "('".$i."','"
    .$_SESSION["redirection"][$j]."','".$_SESSION["username"]$j]."','"
    .$_SESSION["pc"][$j]."','".$_SESSION["date"][$j]."','"
    .$_SESSION["time"][$j]."','".$_SESSION["method"][$j]."','"
    .$_SESSION["text"][$j]."','".$_SESSION["http"][$j]."','"
    .$_SESSION["code"][$j]."','".$_SESSION["data"][$j]."','"
    .$_SESSION["request"][$j]."','".$_SESSION["software"][$j]."')";
    if($i<=$fd){
        $sql1 .= ", ";
    }
}
mysql_query($sql1);
?>
```

In this case you will perform only one insertion instead multiple. Also, as variant, you can store your data into text file (.csv, for example) and then import it into your database. But this is exotic method.

Comment: combine this with disabling keys for extra speed

Comment: also php's execution time and memory limits need to be adjusted for such huge query

Answer (score 0):

Use extended insert syntax to insert multiple rows per statement:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Another trick is to disable/delete indexes and enable/add them after all data has been inserted.

```
DISABLE KEYS;
INSERT ......
ENABLE KEYS;
```

Comment: how would he remove th eindexes dynamically through PHP code while executing the insert query?

Comment: I have to Insert in the table after extracting from text file and saving in session

Comment: Sudeep: I'm not sure what you're saying. Are you saying you don't know how to apply what I suggest, or you don't think it will work for you?

Comment: i have stored data in session which is relevant and i need to store it mysql database faster in about 1-2 min.@Cal your code is making insertion in 5 min i need more faster

Answer (score 0):

If the table supports transactions (InnoDB), you can speed up bulk inserts by doing everything inside a single transaction. Query `BEGIN TRANSACTION` before all the inserts, and `COMMIT` after you're done.

Obviously, this is irrelevant if your table doesn't support transactions (MyISAM).

Prepared statements are another way to speed up bulk inserts (with added security benefits), but it's difficult to do that in a project that uses `mysql_query()` everywhere, so I'll leave that out.

Comment: can you give syntax of that it will be very helpful

Comment: Syntax for what? If you're talking about transactions, just do `mysql_query('BEGIN TRANSACTION');` before the for loop, and `mysql_query('COMMIT');` afterward.

Answer (score 0):

You're not really clear what your limits are, and especially WHY. Other answers assume you are on some sort of time-schedule, and need the insert completed before a certain moment

But when we assume you want to have control over your program back as quickly as possible, but not neccesairily need the insert to be finished, you could use delayed inserts?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html

> The DELAYED option for the INSERT statement is a MySQL extension to
>   standard SQL that is very useful if you have clients that cannot or
>   need not wait for the INSERT to complete. This is a common situation
>   when you use MySQL for logging and you also periodically run SELECT
>   and UPDATE statements that take a long time to complete.
>
> When a client uses INSERT DELAYED, it gets an okay from the server at
>   once, and the row is queued to be inserted when the table is not in
>   use by any other thread.